# Faster way to remove duplicates from a very large text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, duplicates

I have a very large text file with duplicate entries which I want to eliminate. I do not care about the order of the entries because the file will later be sorted.

Here is what I have so far:

```
unique_lines = set()
outfile = open("UniqueMasterList.txt", "w", encoding = "latin-1")

with open("MasterList.txt", "r", encoding = "latin-1") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line not in unique_lines:
            outfile.write(line)
            unique_lines.add(line)

outfile.close()
```

It has been running for 30 minutes and has not finished. I need it to be faster. What is a faster approach *in Python*?

Comment: I would just use `sort -u -o UniqueMasterList.txt MasterList.txt` rather than write any custom code.

Comment: Why don't you sort it first? It will be easy to remove the duplicates then.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you don't need to close `infile` since you opened it using the `with` keyword.

Comment: martianwars, why would it be easier?

Comment: @Kos Any duplicate lines will be immediately adjacent to each other, meaning you don't have to keep the entire unique set in memory.

Comment: When you say "very large file", how large? Any chance it will fit in memory? I presume so, since the `set` will grow too large if not. If you're running a 64-bit version of Python it may be swapping, which would definitely make it too slow.

Comment: It's 5gb, and I have 16gb of RAM. I'm running 64-bit. What do you mean by swapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the same technique as `uniq`, in Python:

```
import itertools
with open("MasterList.txt", "r", encoding = "latin-1") as infile:
    sorted_file = sorted(infile.readlines())
for line, _ in itertools.groupby(sorted_file):
    outfile.write(line)
```

This presumes that the entire file will fit into memory, twice. Or that the file is already sorted and you can skip that step.

Answer (score 6):

Look for the corresponding system command.  In [Linux/UNIX](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/uniq-command-examples/), you would use

```
uniq MasterList.txt > UniqueMasterList.txt
```

The OS generally knows the best way to do these things.

---

**post-comment edit**

*@Mark Ransom* reminded me that uniq depends on matching lines being contiguous in the file.  The simplest way to achieve this is to sort the file:

```
sort MasterList.txt | uniq > UniqueMasterList.txt
```

Comment: Why is it faster? And also (I edited the title to make it more clear), is there a faster way to do this but in Python?

Comment: It's faster because the OS can optimize for its file structure, storage, and access methods.  You can do it faster in Python by calling the system command from your Python script.  A second choice might be to hash the lines to speed up the **in** operator.  For a test on this, insert them into a set instead of a list and see what performance change you get.

Comment: @Prune the original question already uses a `set`. Using a cryptographic hash in place of the original line string might reduce the data load, but it's an open question whether it would be faster.

Comment: P.S. `uniq` only works if the data is *already* sorted, you must pair it with `sort` otherwise. If you don't, it will be *very* fast but incorrect.

Comment: The `sort` command can also be used to remove duplicates directly using the flag `u`. If you are running the code on a multicore system it can also leverage multiple cores, e.g. `sort --parallel=4 -u file-with-duplicates.csv > file-no-duplicates.tsv`.

Comment: On windows 10, if you have wsl, you can use  `wsl uniq`

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach that i would suggest is use of hashing and hash tables.You can hash each line using a efficient hash function and then insert it into a hash table and output contents where count is 1.Similar to solving word /letter count problem using hash tables.For look up it would only cost o(1) and usage of memory can be restricted to a constant amount depending on the size of hash table used.

Answer (score 0):

```
SPLIT_COUNT = 30


def write_data(t_file, value):
    t_file.write(value)


def calculate_hash(filename, handle_file):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:

        for line in f:

            write_data(handle_file[hash(line)%SPLIT_COUNT], line)


def generate_file(dir):

    handle_file, files = [], []

    for i in range(SPLIT_COUNT):

        path = dir+"split_"+str(i)

        files.append(path)

        f = open(path, 'w')

        handle_file.append(f)

    return files, handle_file


def close_file(handle_file):

    for i in range(len(handle_file)):

        handle_file[i].close()


def data_uniq(files, new_file):

    dataset = dict()

    n_file = open(new_file, 'w')

    for filename in files:

        f = open(filename, 'r')

        for line in f:

            dataset[line] = 1

        f.close()

        for key in dataset.keys():

            n_file.write(key)

        dataset = {}

    n_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = './clean.txt'
    generate_dir = './tmp/'
    new_file = './out.txt'
    files, handle_file = generate_file(generate_dir)
    calculate_hash(filename, handle_file)
    close_file(handle_file)
    data_uniq(files, new_file)
```